# How can I get bash completions?

Tags: bash

Is there a nice way to print (e.g. to stdout) a list of all possible completions of a command in bash (the ones it would give me if I typed the command, then pressed tab)?

Edit: I guess this wasn't really clear, now that I read it again.  I know how to get completions manually.  I want to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bash does not have a function to do exactly that. The programmable completions depend heavily on various parameters such as the cursor position...

```
eval $(complete -p 'git' | sed s/^complete/compgen/)
```

*seems* to work, but is very fragile.

Comment: This isn't quite exactly what I wanted, but I guess it's probably as close as I'll get.

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>TAB</kbd> twice. Most BASH-like shells will list all matching auto-completion options for a given substring.

e.g.

```
root@host$apt-get up
```

pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> twice on this command will list both `Update` and `Upgrade`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the `bash-completion` package installed.  Depending on your install type it may or may not be included by default, if not just grab it with `yum` or `apt`.  After installing, you'll need to log out and log back in or re-source your `.bashrc` to use it.

@Amazed is spot on as for how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Not really... remember that the completions can be a function and can be dependent on previous arguments.

That said, `complete | grep ...` might get you someplace

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking for is basically a list of all the commands beginning with a given string.  You should be able to do that by getting a list of all the executables on your system and running them through grep.

Answer (score 0):

(This is ludicrously late to be adding a response, but this thread is what popped up when I looked for this issue, so I will share what I figured out eventually)

```
compgen -A command <command_prefix>
```

(u1686_grawity's comment about completion depending on the position of the cursor in the command line is still relevant, but the command above does work for the case of starting to type a command at the beginning of the line)